# Include background image to ONE tab in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to include a background image that only shows in the "overview"-tab (and not in all tabs) in my shiny application. As far as I understand, its not possible to modify the  [setBackgroundImage](https://dreamrs.github.io/shinyWidgets/reference/setBackgroundImage.html) to apply on certain tab. Instead, I tried modifying the source code but I dont quite understand how to get target the body on the overview-tab.

I have looked at [Adding background image to Shiny NavBarPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35862596/adding-background-image-to-shiny-navbarpage) but I would like to have a solution for the html tags rather than modify the the existing function as suggested there.

```r
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)


ui <- # Define UI for application that draws a histogram
    navbarPage(
        "Old Faithful Geyser Data",
        tabPanel(
            "Overview",
            mainPanel(
                tags$style(
                    HTML(
                        "body {
                    background: url('https://www.fillmurray.com/1920/1080') no-repeat center center fixed;
                    -webkit-background-size: cover;
                    -moz-background-size: cover;
                    -o-background-size: cover;
                    background-size: cover;
                }"
                    ))
            )
            
            
        ),    
        tabPanel("Model",
                 
                 # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
                 sidebarLayout(
                     sidebarPanel(
                         sliderInput("bins",
                                     "Number of bins:",
                                     min = 1,
                                     max = 50,
                                     value = 30)
                     ),
                     
                     # Show a plot of the generated distribution
                     mainPanel(
                         plotOutput("distPlot")
                     )
                 )
        )
        
        
        
    )

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Shiny applications not supported in static R Markdown documents

<sup>Created on 2021-09-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can inject these pice of Javascript:

```
function updateBgImage() {
    if ($("li.active")[0].firstElementChild.dataset.value == "Overview") {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://www.fillmurray.com/1920/1080')"
    } else {
        document.body.style.background = "transparent"
    }   
}

$("ul.nav").click(updateBgImage)
```

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the order on your suggested if-solution since I only get the png on the tab not named "Overview".  In addition, the png only appears after having switched to the desired tab. I want to have the png included to the overview tab aslo when the app is launched.

Comment: You can run `document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://www.fillmurray.com/1920/1080')"` additionally on startup.